# fixed div width more than intended

Tags: html, css

take a look at the footer div [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uHX63/) which contains `all rights reserved`

all 3 divs have a width of 70%, but the footer's width is displayed more than intended

```
#header{
width:70%;
margin: 0 auto;
background:#CCCCCC;}

#container{
width:70%;
margin: 0 auto;
background:#CCCCCC;
}

#footer{
width:70%;
background:#000000;
color:#FFFFFF;
position:fixed;bottom:0;
left:15%;
}
```

Comment: With no default body margin: http://jsfiddle.net/uHX63/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the default margin/padding on the body element. it's a good idea to use a reset at the top of your css for consistency. ie

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

This will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

reset the margin, padding for body.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHX63/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer{
    width:68%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:#000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position:fixed;bottom:0;
    left:16%;
    }
```

or can reset the body padding and margin

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```